# Flutter + Sonoma OSX Update Breaks Hot Reload and Hot Restart

Tags: flutter, macos-sonoma, flutter-hotreload, flutter-hotrestart

After updating my OSX to Sonoma recently, my Flutter Dev Environment can no longer hot reload.

I keep getting this error message when VS Code tries to hot reload or hot restart:

```
Failed to Hot Reload: DebugAdapterException: Flutter failed to create file at "/Users/hotdog/Library/Containers/com.example.firstApp/Data/tmp/first_app2fr7NB/first_app/main.dart.incremental.dill".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
```

Similar message for Hot Restart:

```
Failed to Hot Restart: DebugAdapterException: Flutter failed to create file at "/Users/hotdog/Library/Containers/com.example.firstApp/Data/tmp/first_appnSNkrN/first_app/main.dart.dill".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
```

With the exception of the Android toolchain, since I'm not developing for android, calling`flutter doctor` checks out without any issues.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Looking at `/Users/hotdog/Library/Containers/`, the folder `com.example.firstApp` does not even exist.

Has anyone else experienced this?

I'm guessing it has something to do with permissions being reset since the update, specifically to the `~/Library/Containers` folder.

Comment: I also had this problem. Manual hot reload/restart was broken, but after restarting vscode and saving a file while the app was running, vscode presented a dialog about allowing sharing between apps (or some such). Selecting 'Allow' fixed the permissions issue.